# Converting CHAR string to nth letter in Alphabet string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to build a process that takes a VARCHAR string (for example 'AHT559') and converts it to a INT only string by converting the Alphabetic chars to INTEGERS based on the nth letter in the alphabet. The above would thus result in: 010820559.

I have done this in SAS before, but I'm relatively new to SQL. What would be the best way to do this in SQL?

Here is what I've done in SAS:

```
DO _i = 1 TO length( account );
        IF (rank( char( account, _i ) ) -64)  < 0 THEN agreement_hash = CATS( agreement_hash, char( account, _i ) );
        ELSE IF  (rank( char( account, _i ) ) -64) < 10 THEN agreement_hash = CATS( agreement_hash, 0, rank( char( account, _i ) )-64 );
        ELSE agreement_hash = CATS( agreement_hash, rank( char( account, _i ) )-64 );
    END;
```

Comment: do your values have any standard format? as in 3 characters always followed by 3 numbers? also, will you only process one value at a time or will this select a column of values from a table?

Comment: @Tanner my values will always be in that format. I will only process one value at a time and then after iterating through this string, I will Concatenate all the results into one new string.

Comment: @Herm if you want efficiency over that amount of data (4m values as per comment on t-clausen's answer), you need stronger tools. Since your requirements are to iterate 1 at a time, and have a simple scalar translation without data access, a CLR UDF will be a good performer. See [here](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2013/07/22/clr-vs-t-sql-performance-considerations/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar script for sqlserver, any character which is not a capital letter is assumed a digit in this syntax:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100) = 'AHT559'
DECLARE @p int = len(@x)

WHILE @p > 0
SELECT @x = 
  CASE WHEN substring(@x, @p, 1) between 'A' and 'Z' 
  THEN stuff(@x, @p, 1, right(ascii(substring(@x, @p, 1)) - 64 + 100, 2))
  ELSE @x END,
  @p -= 1

SELECT @x
```

Result:

```
010820559
```

Comment: this is perfect! Will this be an efficient solution if I have to implement this on approx. 4mil rows of data?

Comment: updating 4 mil rows will never be painless. If you know that the first 3 characters are always letters, it can be modified to be more effective. This method could be wrapped in a function.

Answer (score 5):

If the format of the values is always the same as you state in the comments and you only need to process a single value at a time you can do some simple string manipulation to convert the characters to integers using their [ASCII values](http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php), and subtracting 64 to get the number of the alphabetic character:

```
SELECT ASCII('A')      -- produces 65
SELECT ASCII('A') - 64 -- produces 1
```

This is a little long winded and could be done in less lines of code, but it's separated for clarity.

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(10) = 'AHT559'

-- get first, second and third character numeric values
DECLARE @first INT = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@val, 1, 1)) - 64
DECLARE @second INT = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@val, 2, 1)) - 64
DECLARE @third INT = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@val, 3, 1)) - 64

-- join them together adding a '0' if < 10
SELECT  RIGHT('0' + CAST(@first  AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
      + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@second AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
      + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@third  AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
      + RIGHT(@val, 3)
```

Tested on 4 million rows:

```
-- temp table creation - takes approx 100 seconds on my machine
CREATE TABLE #temp (val NVARCHAR(6))

DECLARE  @rowno INT = 1
SELECT @rowno = 1
WHILE @rowno <= 4000000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp ( val ) VALUES  ( 'AHT559' )
    SELECT @rowno = @rowno + 1
END
```

To run this code against the entire temp table takes < 20 seconds on my machine:

```
SELECT val AS OrignalValue,
        RIGHT('0' + CAST( ASCII(SUBSTRING(val, 1, 1)) - 64  AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
      + RIGHT('0' + CAST( ASCII(SUBSTRING(val, 2, 1)) - 64 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
      + RIGHT('0' + CAST( ASCII(SUBSTRING(val, 3, 1)) - 64  AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
      + RIGHT(val, 3) AS FormattedValue
FROM #temp
```

Comment: This is much better, plus it an be easily turned into a iTVF.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the below, possibly as a scalar function to do this conversion.

```
DECLARE @i INT    
DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000) = 'AHT1234'

DECLARE @ItemTable TABLE 
(
    Item NCHAR(1)
)

SET @i = 1

--Split the input string into separate characters, store in temp table
WHILE (@i <= LEN(@Item))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) 
    VALUES(SUBSTRING(@Item, @i, 1))
    SET @i = @i + 1
END 


DECLARE @AlphaTable TABLE (
    Letter NCHAR(1),
    Position NVARCHAR(2)
)

-- Populate this with the whole alphabet obviously.  Could be a permanent rather than temp table.
INSERT INTO @AlphaTable
        ( Letter, Position )
VALUES  ( N'A', '01'),
          (N'H', '08'),
          (N'T', '20')  

DECLARE @Output NVARCHAR(50)

-- Convert the output and concatenate it back to a single output.
SELECT @Output = COALESCE(@output, '') + Converted
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Item) = 1
        THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1), Item)
        ELSE (SELECT Position FROM @AlphaTable WHERE Letter = CONVERT(NCHAR(1), Item))
        END AS Converted
    FROM @ItemTable
) AS T1

SELECT @Output
```

GO

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @STR    VARCHAR(MAX)= 'AHT559',
        @SP     INT,
        @SP_STR VARCHAR(50),
        @OUTPUT VARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @TEMP_STR VARCHAR(50)

SET @TEMP_STR = @STR

WHILE Patindex('%[A-Z]%', @TEMP_STR) <> 0
  BEGIN
      SELECT @SP = Patindex('%[A-Z]%', @TEMP_STR)
      SELECT @SP_STR = Upper(LEFT(@TEMP_STR, @SP))
      SELECT @SP_STR = ( Ascii(@SP_STR) - 65 ) + 1
      SELECT @TEMP_STR = Stuff(@TEMP_STR, 1, @SP, '')
      SET @OUTPUT += RIGHT('0' + @SP_STR, 2)
  END

SELECT @OUTPUT + Substring(@STR, Patindex('%[0-9]%', @STR), Len(@STR))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a CTE to create every combination of the first 3 letters and using that to match to:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1b0b/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts
(
    Account VARCHAR(6)
)

INSERT INTO Accounts
VALUES ('AHT559'), ('BXC556'),
       ('CST345')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH AlphaToNum
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('A', '01'), ('B', '02'), ('C', '03'), ('D', '04'),
        ('E', '05'), ('F', '06'), ('G', '07'), ('H', '08'),
        ('I', '09'), ('J', '10'), ('K', '11'), ('L', '12'),
        ('M', '13'), ('N', '14'), ('O', '15'), ('P', '16'),
        ('Q', '17'), ('R', '18'), ('S', '19'), ('T', '20'),
        ('U', '21'), ('V', '22'), ('W', '23'), ('X', '24'),
        ('Y', '25'), ('Z', '26')
        ) X(alpha, num)
),
MappingTable
As
(
    SELECT  A1.alpha + A2.alpha + A3.alpha as match, A1.num + A2.num + A3.num as val
    FROM AlphaToNum A1
    CROSS APPLY AlphaToNum A2
    CROSS APPLY AlphaToNum A3
)
SELECT A.Account, M.val + SUBSTRING(A.Account,4, 3) As ConvertedAccount
FROM MappingTable M
INNER JOIN Accounts A
    ON LEFT(A.Account,3) = M.match
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1b0b/3/0)**:

```
| Account | ConvertedAccount |
|---------|------------------|
|  AHT559 |        010820559 |
|  BXC556 |        022403556 |
|  CST345 |        031920345 |
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably best done using a CLR UDF, but a full answer is too long for this format.

Basically you need to create a UDF (User defined function) that takes a string (nvarchar...) as an input and returns a string as an output. You can do that with C# quite easily, and you need to wrap it with the CLR integration requirements.

You can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131089.aspx) for relevant information.

The code could look something like:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(
   IsDeterministic=true,
   IsPrecise=true,
   SystemDataAccess=SystemDataAccessKind.None)]
public static SqlString ToNthAlpha(SqlString value)
{
   if(value.IsNull)
      return value;

   char []chars = value.Value.ToCharArray();
   StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
   {
       if(chars[i] >= 'A' && chars[i] <= 'Z')
          res.AppendFormat("{0:00}", chars[i] - 'A');
       res.Append(chars[i]);
   }

   return new SqlString(res.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What's the point of -1 without a comment to explain yourself?

Comment: I am the original poster of this question and I'm also not sure why it received a downvote. Even though it isn't the accepted answer, it did lead me to a different way of thinking. If I was more experienced in SQL/C# , I would've probably been able to use this as the solution.

Comment: @Herm - I added a C# function that should be able to do what you want. Unfortunately I can't test it at the moment, but even if it's not accurate it shouldn't be far off or difficult to fix. You can give it a try, and see if it improves performance.